# iterate the string in every row and count the variable if attribute value is greater then 1

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a string as showing below

```
[["","","2","1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0"],["","","0","0","0","1","2","3","2","0","0","0"],["","","0","0","1","2","2","1","1","1","2","0"],["","","0","0","0","1","2","2","2","1","0","0"]]
```

I have broken each list as rows using below query

```
 with dataa (d) as
   (SELECT '[["","","2","1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0"],["","","0","0","0","1","2","3","2","0","0","0"],["","","0","0","1","2","2","1","1","1","2","0"],["","","0","0","0","1","2","2","2","1","0","0"]]' from dual)
   select level, '[' || ltrim(ltrim(regexp_substr(d,'[^]]+',1,level) || ']',','),'[') as str
    from dataa
  connect by level <= regexp_count(d,'\[') - 1;
```

This is the result:

[image]

Now i want counter value of each row if number is greater then 1

```
1 row --> 1
2 row --> 3
.....
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following query in `for loop`:

```
with dataa (d) as
(select '[["","","2","1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0"],["","","0","0","0","1","2","3","2","0","0","0"],["","","0","0","1","2","2","1","1","1","2","0"],["","","0","0","0","1","2","2","2","1","0","0"]]' from dual)
-- query starts from
SELECT CNTR
  FROM
    (SELECT T.STR, REGEXP_SUBSTR(T.STR, '[0-9]+',1,COLUMN_VALUE) AS CNTR, COLUMN_VALUE AS LVL, LVLIN
       FROM
           (select '[' || ltrim(ltrim(regexp_substr(d,'[^]]+',1,level) || ']',','),'[') as str, LEVEL AS LVLIN
              from dataa
            connect by level <= regexp_count(d,'\[') - 1) T
     CROSS JOIN
     table(cast(multiset(select level from dual
                         connect by  level <= length (regexp_replace(t.STR, '[^,]+'))  + 1)
                          as sys.OdciNumberList)) levels)
ORDER BY LVLIN, LVL;
```

Comment: Thanks output is expected but is this possible we can achieve the same using loop so that we can perform other operations on each element.

like first we can add each row in list and then can iterate each element

Answer (score 0):

After you splitted row, you can take only numbers between 2-9 .

```sql
with dataa (d)
     as (select '[["","","2","1","1","1","1","0","0","0","0","0"],["","","0","0","0","1","2","3","2","0","0","0"],["","","0","0","1","2","2","1","1","1","2","0"],["","","0","0","0","1","2","2","2","1","0","0"]]'
           from DUAL)
select lev,length(regexp_replace(str, '[^2-9]', ''))
  from (    select LEVEL lev,                      
                    REGEXP_SUBSTR (d,
                                     '[^]]+',
                                     1,
                                     LEVEL)
                      as str
              from dataa
        connect by LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT (d, '\[') - 1)
```